# Is it a good idea to delegate addition to in-place addition for custom classes?

Tags: python, oop, operator-overloading

Given a custom class that needs to support addition, are there any reasons not to delegate the `__add__` method to `__iadd__` such that:

```
def __add__(self, other): 
    if not self.comparable(other):
        raise ValueError("Objects cannot be added!")

    temp = copy.deepcopy(self)
    temp += other
    return temp

def __iadd__(self, other):
    if not self.comparable(other):
        raise ValueError("Objects cannot be added!")

    self.x += other.x
    self.y += other.y
    # ... whatever else addition voodoo
```

I cannot come up with anything besides the fact that `copy.deepcopy` might be an issue for memory but since addition is **supposed to** return a new object and leave `self` unchanged, I am not sure it can be avoided. An alternative would be to instantiate a new object with the constructor, which isn't really a neat option if the class has many mutable variables. In my case here it's a stochastic model that's generated from a whole chunk of training data, so it was easier to get a copy.

All in all the above definitions do comply with the requirements, but I have not seen this type of dependency between the two methods in any tutorial which makes me a bit suspicious.

Is this in any way dangerous or bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly very much the natural and recommended way of doing things in C++.

On the other hand, if you have immutable objects (like the basic integer or string types) you won't have an `__iadd__` and will have to implement `__add__` directly.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) if you don't have an `__iadd__`, `x += y` will invoke either `x.__add__(y)` or `y.__radd__(x)` and then assign the result to x.